Someone giving me a bitcoin wallet address into the crypto app I just bought £150 worth bitcoin
Someone has told me they can help me make some money on crypto by buying some bitcoin and getting some good returns whilst they will get a 5% cut on profit.  They did say I could start small.  So I bought bitcoin on my crypto app they guided me step by step by screen shots.  Noe I have come to the wallet bit and they have given me a BTC wallet address to input on the app - a bitcoin address.  Now I am thinking are they going to get access to my app?  or is it safe for me to input the Bitcoin address they have given me?  I have checked the address they have given me it starts with bc1...... and is long.  Can you help?

This is 100% a scam. Don't send them any bitcoin.

After in putting the wallet address - does the bitcoins go to them?

Yes, if you send an amount of bitcoin to an address given to you by a third party, that amount will go to them. In this case I suspect not only will you never get that bitcoin back, but they will make up excuses to make you send them even more.

Thanks for this advice really appreciate it!


is it safe for me to input the Bitcoin address they have given me?

Doing anything they ask is unsafe. Continuing to communicate with them in any way is unsafe. Your computer may now be unsafe to use.
They have already tricked you and stolen your money. Addresses are public and putting an address into a wallet doesn't give you control over money sent to that address.
Bitcoin wallets don't contain money, they normally contain the numbers called private-keys that give control over money sent to addresses derived from those keys. Wallets are also a kind of window onto the blockchain and can show amounts of money associated with addresses - but if you don't have the private keys you cant spend that money.
The person you spoke with will encourage you to invest more and more. They will trick you by making the wallet show you huge profits that you really don't control.
When you want to withdraw your fake profits, they will falsely say you have to pay some special fee in advance.
When they have bled you dry they will drop contact and move on to other victims, ignoring you.
You have no way to recover money you gave them but can report fraud to your local police.
